# Subversion SVN (VERSION 1.6.6) svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS error

Tags: svn

Here is my problem, every time I try to download the SVN from: http://3ceam.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rewrite
I get the following error:

svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS error

I have been reading stuff on google but I cannot find a solution. Could anyone help with this?
Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Works for me, how did you try to check out ? (sorry didn't pay attention to the title I have svn 1.6.12)

Comment: No problem either...just used the browser...

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities come to mind here:
Either you're behind a firewall/proxy that rejects DAV requests, google code has a hiccup and it will work soon again, or you use the wrong url: if you access the repository and you already have username/password for that repository saved, you might want to try the `https://` url instead of the `http://` url.